# Display a relationship column in HTML with mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have a mvc controller name "Usuarios" which index display 3 columns of the Usuarios table in my DB, because of having relations problems in the database, we created a relational table between "Usuarios" and "Cursos" (1 "usuarios" can have N "curos" and the other way around). So now I'm trying to display the "cursos" name (which is related with "usuarios" by the relational table) on the "Usuarios" index.html.

How can I do this?

This is my index.cshtml code and in the last TD I would like to add the Cursos.name which is in another table that haves a relational table with the "Usuarios" table.

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DNI)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor()
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.idUsuario}) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.idUsuario }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.idUsuario })
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Are you asking about a database query? Do you have some code you can post?

Comment: I dont really know if I need a query. I have 3 tables. "Cursos" , "Usuarios" , "Relaciones" (this one having curos_id and usuarios_id to act as a realtional table.) And I want to display "Cursos.name" in the index view of the "Usuarios controller", they are just realted by this 3rd party table ("Relaciones")-

Comment: Have you looked at the model on the server, using a breakpoint? Check to see if the data is there, as it might not be reading it from the DB.

Comment: Can you show us your Model?

Answer (score 0):

Use include when get data from database.

.Include("Cursos")

Then use

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cursos.Nombre)
```

Comment: where can i write that Include?

Comment: dbContext.Usuarios. Include("Cursos")

Comment: thats in the view, rihght? my model in there is @model IEnumerable<LibreriaEntidad.Cursos>

Comment: the problem is that the "Cursos" and "Usuarios" have no realtionship. They realted related via a relationional table with bot idCurso and idUsuario. and so, I cannot include Cursos in db.Usuarios because there is no direct relation between team

Comment: Please send a image of your model